# How do I add scroll arrows to Mint 17.2?

Tags: scroll, linux-mint

There are no scroll arrows in my current Mint 17.2 setup. I'm using this system on a laptop and it's hard to go without these, especially when reading documents or browsing webpages that are longer than a few pages. I've tried switching the desktop theme from Cinnamon to MATE to Mint XP but that didn't help. Does anybody have a solution?

If you're not sure what I mean by scroll arrows, see this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC79322.gif

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a solution in this thread: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=205950&p=1072782#p1072782